# Looping through controls and using a function

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have many `Panels`, `Labels` and `PictureBox`'s and i have a function witch I use like this
`myFunction(panel1,label2,pictureBox3);` and I have to write about 40 lines only with this line of code ...

I want to know if there is a way to make a function loop through all the elements I need ... something like ...
`while(i==40){myFunction(panel[i],label[i],pictureBox[i]); i++;}`

Comment: Use `this.Controls.OfType<Panel>()` and so on. BTW, if you're concerned with the quality of your code you shouldn't be using winforms to begin with...

Comment: `i == 40` is not a great loop condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the `Controls` collection of forms and container controls.  But the problem you're going to run into is how to properly associate one with the others.  If they're always in these groups of three, then looping through *all* controls doesn't seem to have a way to determine which intuitive grouping each control belongs to.

And even if it did, it's not something I'd want to rely on.

Instead, you can track this "grouping" at the form level.  It could be something as simple as a custom object, like this:

```
class PanelPictureGroup
{
    public Panel GroupPanel { get; set; }
    public Label GroupLabel { get; set; }
    public PictureBox GroupPictureBox { get; set; }
}
```

By itself the object doesn't do anything, but you can initialize a collection of them when your form loads.  Something like:

```
private List<PanelPictureGroup> myGroups = new List<PanelPictureGroup>();
```

and in a load event, or somewhere in the form:

```
myGroups.Add(new PanelPictureGroup { GroupPanel = panel1, GroupLabel = label2, GroupPictureBox = pictureBox3 });
myGroups.Add(new PanelPictureGroup { GroupPanel = panel4, GroupLabel = label5, GroupPictureBox = pictureBox6 });
// and so on, probably abstracted into a form initialization method and called once on form load
```

At this point all of your controls are actually in logical groups, explicitly set as such.  (Rather than trying to infer the groups based on assumptions of the control "numbers" which are entirely arbitrary.)  Now looping through them is trivial:

```
foreach (var myGroup in myGroups)
    myFunction(myGroup.GroupPanel, myGroup.GroupLabel, myGroup.GroupPictureBox);
```

The more logic that can be encapsulated into the object, the better.  As Eric Raymond once said, "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around."

Comment: Well .. this means that I need to add to the group every control ... so this means even more effort than just writing 40 lines of a function ...

Comment: @S0DDesign: This also means your controls are meaningfully grouped into objects on which you can add further functionality.  You can reference individual groups as well, perhaps changing the `List<>` to a `Dictionary<>` where you can reference groups by meaningful names.  Without knowing anything about the functionality being achieved, I can't say for sure if any of that is necessary.  The point, however, is to rely on objects and meaningful data structures instead of procedural code.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    var panel = this.Controls
        .OfType<Panel>()
        .First(p => p.Name == string.Format("panel{0}"))
    var label = this.Controls
        .OfType<Label>()
        .First(p => p.Name == string.Format("label{0}"));
    var panel = this.Controls
        .OfType<PictureBox>()
        .First(p => p.Name == string.Format("pictureBox{0}"));

    myFunction(panel, label, pictureBox);
}
```

Comment: You might want `First` or `Single` instead of `Where` so you actually get the control.

Comment: What i need to import in order to use `OfType` ?

Comment: @S0DDesign, add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the `.cs` file.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I am using .NET Framework 2.0 so I can not use `System.Linq` because it needs .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: @S0DDesign, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to retrieve all those controls based on their names using Controls.Find() with code like this:

```
        Panel pnl;
        Label lbl;
        PictureBox pb;
        Control[] matches;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i = i + 3)
        {
            matches = this.Controls.Find("panel" + i.ToString(), true);
            if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Panel)
            {
                pnl = matches[0] as Panel;
                matches = this.Controls.Find("label" + (i + 1).ToString(), true);
                if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Label)
                {
                    lbl = matches[0] as Label;
                    matches = this.Controls.Find("pictureBox" + (i + 2).ToString(), true);
                    if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is PictureBox)
                    {
                        pb = matches[0] as PictureBox;

                        myFunction(pnl, lbl, pb);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**You could use code like this in the Load() event of the Form to populate the Groups proposed by David, which is a good idea.**

Comment: Also, if these three items are visually linked, then a **UserControl** made from them might make more sense as they will be one "unit" instead of three separate controls.